# How do you debug a referenced dll from a process you are already attached to

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, dll, step-into

I hope that title wasnt confusing.

So I have a Windows Service that I am debugging by "Attaching to Process". This Windows service references a dll that is built in another project and built through TeamCity, then referenced through Nuget.

I would like to debug the referenced dll via the code I already have. Basically "step through it".

Is this possible? I tried to do Debug-Windows-Module then Load Symbols but I got an error like this: "a matching symbol was not found in this folder"

Is it possible to accomplish what I want to do?

Also I am using VS2012 if that helps at all.

Comment: Clearly you'll need a valid PDB for the DLL first.  It is entirely unclear why the debugger can't find it.  Use the Symbol Load Information context menu item to see where it looked.

Comment: True I need a pdb, and I manually reference it by doing a Load Symbols. Maybe because TeamCity builds my dll it wont like my pdb file?

Answer (score 0):

Create DLL in Debug mode and set all Enable Debugging Options And then add reference of that dll to your project

To set Debugging options Go to
Properties->Debug->Enable Debugging